# KnockoutJS - ViewModel (Grandparent - Parent - Child) Accessing a Parent Function within Child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js, parent-child

I have a Grandparent, Parent, Child ViewModel relationship setup in knockout and knockout mapping,  CustomerViewModel, WorkOrderViewModel, and RepairViewModel.

For each level I flag if the record has been Modified.  Then I have a save button that saves the entire Model.  The function that Saves the Model is within the Grandparent ViewModel (CustomerViewModel)

Example of a Child level element

```
<input class="form-control input-sm text-right" name="RepairCost" id="RepairCost" data-bind="value: RepairCost, event: {change: flagRepairAsEdited}" />
```

Is there a way within the flagRepairAsEdited function I can call the SAVE function within the parent/grandparent?

Thanks so much!

Here is the JS code I'm using (simplified):

```
var ObjectState = {
    Unchanged: 0,
    Added: 1,
    Modified: 2,
    Deleted: 3
};

var workOrderMapping = {
    'WorkOrders': {
        key: function (workOrders) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(workOrders.WorkOrderId);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return new WorkOrderViewModel(options.data);
        }
    },

    'Repairs': {
        key: function (repairs) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(repairs.RepairId);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return new RepairViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
};

RepairViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, workOrderMapping, self);


    self.flagRepairAsEdited = function () {
        if (self.ObjectState() != ObjectState.Added) {
            self.ObjectState(ObjectState.Modified);
        }
//WOULD LOVE TO CALL SAVE FUNCTION HERE
        return true;
    }
    ;
}

WorkOrderViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, workOrderMapping, self);

    self.flagWorkOrderAsEdited = function () {
        if (self.ObjectState() != ObjectState.Added) {
            self.ObjectState(ObjectState.Modified);
        }
      //WOULD LOVE TO CALL SAVE FUNCTION HERE
        return true;
    }
    ;

}

CustomerViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, workOrderMapping, self);

    self.save = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Customers/Save/",
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data.customerViewModel, workOrderMapping, self);

                if (data.newLocation != null)
                    window.location = data.newLocation;
            },

        });
    },
    self.flagCustomerAsEdited = function () {

        if (self.ObjectState() != ObjectState.Added) {

            self.ObjectState(ObjectState.Modified);

        }

        return true;
    }
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways to do this

a) Pass viewModels as parameters of the child `flagRepairAsEdited` function:

```
data-bind="value: RepairCost, event: {change: flagRepairAsEdited.bind($data, $parent, $root)}"
```

b) Save the link of the parent viewModel inside child viewModel

```
WorkOrderViewModel = function (data, parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    ...
}
```

And use `parent.flagWorkOrderAsEdited` and `parent.parent.flagWorkOrderAsEdited` to save parent and grandparent viewmodels